# "Refactor this" keyboard shortcut not working properly in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring

Recently I updated IntelliJ IDEA to version 2018.1. I used to have Refactor this bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> and it always showed me little list with what I can do. After updating it always only renames variables, methods etc. I checked keyboard binding and it's correct.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last update to `181.4668.78` brought several issues to all developers in our office. The most seen one is `you can type something into a PHP file but you cannot delete or reverse it by keyboard`. We are forced to use the `Edit` menu then. This problem did not occur at any time but at many times. And there are several other problems like hanging or so. This issues are OS independent.

I recommend a rollback to the previous release which could be done easily if you are using the `JetBrains Toolbox` and had it installed at least with the previous PHPStorm release. So under the settings of PHPStorm (in the Toolbox)  you can perform the rollback to previous `ToolBox` installed releases.

Comment: As of today the latest update solved my problems. So I assume its safe to roll it out.